# prove this set is homeomorphic to a circle

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would like some help on the following question.

Can anyone find a homeomorphic mapping $h : \{(x,y)|x^2 + y^2 =1\} \longrightarrow \{(x,y)|x^2 + y^4 =1\} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h(x,y)=\left \{ \begin{array}{rl}
(x,\sqrt y) & \text{ if } y\geq0\\
(x,-\sqrt {-y}) & \text{ if } y<0)
\end{array}
\right.$

Comment: Thank you! Can you generalize your answer for the case of 3 dimensions? E.g $ h : \{(x,y,z)|x^2 + y^2 +z^2=1\} \longrightarrow \{(x,y,z)|x^2 + y^4 +z^6=1\} $

Comment: if $(x,y,z)$ stay in the second set hence $x^2+(y^2)^2+(z^3)^2$ so $h^{-1}(x,y,z)=(x,\pm y^2,z^3)$