# prove this set is homeomorphic to a n-ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would like some help on the following question.

Can anyone find a homeomorphic mapping $h : \{(x_1,x_2,..,x_n) |\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{2i} =1\} \longrightarrow$
$\{(x_1,x_2,..,x_n) |\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{2} =1\}$

It's actually a generalization of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402040/prove-this-set-is-homeomorphic-to-a-circle/4402049#4402049).

Comment: What have you tried? Can you find a generalization of Bongo's function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:-

$$(x_{i})_{1\leq i\leq n}\mapsto (y_{i})_{1\leq i\leq n}$$

Where $$y_{2i-1}=(x_{2i-1})^{\frac{1}{2i-1}}$$

and $$y_{2i}=\begin{cases}(x_{2i})^{\frac{1}{2i}}\,,x_{2i}\geq 0\\ -(-x_{2i})^{\frac{1}{2i}}\,,x_{2i}<0\end{cases}$$